# Regex: Contains string exact n times

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that is true when a string contains a substring exact for example 2 times. So

`asdgsadg hello asdadsg hello dasadg` would be true

`asdgsadg hello asdadsg hello dasadg hello` would be false

when the substring is `hello`

Unfortunately I can't do `/hello/g` and count the length...

Thanks!

Comment: Did you accidentally mean `substring` instead of `word`? I think *string contains a word exactly for example 2 times* is appropriate.

Comment: `(hello.*){2}` but that also matches 3 times because of the `.*`. So I should add something like "not another time" I guess?!

Comment: What's wrong with `str.match(/hello/g).length == 2 ? console.log('Y') : console.log('N')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is:

```
/^(?!(.*hello){N+1})(.*hello){N}.*$/
```

Where `'N+1' = 3` and `'N' = 2` if you want to allow exactly 2 `hello`.

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/mdaqno/1).

Comment: thanks! I added that for line breaks included and it works as expected!

`/^(?!([.\s\S]*hello){3})([.\s\S]*hello){2}[.\s\S]*$/`

Comment: The dot `.` in square brackets is literal, so it is redundant with respect to `\S` ([see](https://regex101.com/r/yETAeL/1)). Just use `[\s\S]` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
/^(?:(?!\bhello\b).)*(?:\bhello\b(?:(?!\bhello\b).)*){2}$/
```

```js
var test = [
    'asdadsg hello dasadg',
    'asdgsadg hello asdadsg hello dasadg',
    'asdgsadg hello asdadsg hello dasadg hello',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/^(?:(?!\bhello\b).)*(?:\bhello\b(?:(?!\bhello\b).)*){2}$/.test(a);
}));
```

**Explanation:**

```
/
  ^
  (?:                   : non capture group
    (?!\bhello\b).      : asserts there is not hello, followed by a character
  )*                    : group repeated 0 or more times
  (?:                   : non capture group
    \bhello\b           : hello
    (?:                 : non capture group
      (?!\bhello\b).    : asserts there is not hello, followed by a character
    )*                  : group repeated 0 or more times
  ){2}                  : group repeated twice
  $
/
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants this `asdgsadg hello asdadsg hello dasadghello` to be matched.

Comment: @revo: Who knows? In this case, just remove the word boundary

Answer (score 0):

Here the simplest solution I've found so far
`/^(.*hello.*){/*amount to catch here*/}$/g`

Comment: That would also be true for `sdfsd hello sfgsdfg hello sdfgdfg hello dfg` because the 2. hello would be counted as `*.` and it would match the 1. and 3. so it's not exact n times but >=n.